# Setting default value to a field with ORM annotations and handling queries

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to avoid entering **0** or **1** for `$locked` field manually so I assigned default as **0** in `@ORM` annotations however it doesn't work as expected so I'm getting error below. I though `options={"default"=0}` would handle it but appears as it does not handle it!

Is there a way of assigning 0 by defauls so that the INSERT statement doesn't fail?

**Note:** I can sort it out with a `prePersist()` method, `__construct()` or `$locked = 0;` so on but what I'm interested in is @ORM annotation solution.

If @ORM annotation doesn't handle it what is the point of having `options={"default"=0}` since it markes fields default value in database? See image below.

[image]

**Error**:

```
DBALException: An exception occurred while executing "INSERT INTO user (username, locked) VALUES (?, ?)" with params ["username", null]:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column "locked" cannot be null
```

**User Entity**:

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 * @ORM\column(type="boolean", options={"default"=0})
 */
protected $locked;
```

**Controller**:

```
$user: new USer();
$user->setUsername('username');
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 * @ORM\column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $locked = 0;
```

or:

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 * @ORM\column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $locked = false;
```

**UPDATE**

> Doctrine does not support to set the default values in columns through
>   the “DEFAULT” keyword in SQL.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/faq.html#how-can-i-add-default-values-to-a-column

Comment: As far as I know there is no annotation that handles that.

Comment: Try `@ORM\column(type="boolean", options={"default"=false})`. Will that do it?

Comment: No it doesn't either.

Comment: Looks like they have it in the docs - http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/faq.html#how-can-i-add-default-values-to-a-column

Comment: The quote in the answer is possibly outdated now. The [comment by dmnptr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239221/setting-default-value-to-a-field-with-orm-annotations-and-handling-queries#comment41157759_26239381) should now work. See the [Annotations reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column).

Answer (score 1):

With Doctrine ORM v3 you can do it using the `options` property at the `Column` attribute:

```
#[Column(
    type: "integer",
    nullable: false,
    options: ["default" => 0]
)]
protected $loginCount;
```

See https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/attributes-reference.html#column

But Doctrine seems not to encourage this as they negate the possibility here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/faq.html#how-can-i-add-default-values-to-a-column